# OCaml - Identifying the type of this function

Tags: types, ocaml

I'm currently going through some practice problems for a midterm, but I seem to be stuck on identifying the type of this function by walking through it (not even sure where to start).

```
let compose f g = (fun x -> (f (g x)))
```

Any help/ guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `compose` function has two arguments, so it should have type:

```
'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

(this `'a`, `'b` and `'c` are type variables, just a placeholders, we will refine them in the process of derivation).

This type means: take arguments of type `'a` and `'b` correspondingly and return a value of type `'c`.

Let's move forward, to the right hand side of the `=` we see a function of one argument, that means that `'c` must be an arrow type also:

```
'a -> 'b -> ('d -> 'e)
```

So, the return value is a function that accepts a value of type `'d` that is named `x`. But we can see, that `g` function is also applied to this value, that means, that the second parameter of our original function, that had type `'b` actually must be a function, that accepts a value of type `'d` also:

```
'a -> ('d -> 'f) -> ('d -> 'e)
```

Next we see, that first parameter `f`, that had type `'a` is also a function that is applied to whatever `g` returns. That means, that it must be a function that accepts `'f` and returns some value. But since the return value of function `f` is the return value of the `compose` function, that means that it should return `'e`, so

```
('f -> 'e) -> ('d -> 'f) -> ('d -> 'e)
```

Now, lets perform a renaming, to make it look better:

```
('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> ('c -> 'b)
```

And finally, since `->` associates to the right we can remove the last two parenthesis:

```
('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it, and it was exactly structured like what I was looking for. However, the sentence that tripped me up was : So, the return value is a function that accepts a value of type 'e that is named x. Did you not mean 'd?

Answer (score 1):

So the function definition is:

`val compose : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b = <fun>`

The first set of parentheses: ('a -> 'b) says that f is a function that takes 'a and returns something of 'b

The second set of parentheses: ('c -> 'a) says that g is a function that takes something of type 'c and returns something of type 'a.

The last part 'c -> 'b says we return a function that takes something of type 'c and returns something of 'b.

To see why those types are assigned we can start by looking at this:

`(g x)`

So we see that g has the variable x applied to it. So g must be a function. So we can look at x assign it a type 'c. Since x:'c is applied to g, g must take 'c as a parameter and return something. Let's say it returns something of 'a. We also know that the applied expression `(g x)` returns something of type 'a.

Next lets look at:
`(f (g x)))`

Since `(g x):'a` is applied to f. So f must also be a function. Since it is applied something of 'a we now know that it takes something of type 'a as a parameter. We can then say it returns something of type 'b. The applied expression `(f (g x)))` returns something of type 'b.

If my explaination confused you just let me know and I'll try to clairfy.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I found it helpful as a supplement to the other answer, as I was looking for a forward moving answer rather than a backwards one.